# Managed metadata field in Create page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have a managed metadata field added in my list. How to include this field in my custom 'Create' page? I have tried the below code, but its not rendering. Any idea on this ?

```
<strong><PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">Help Contexts:</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel></strong>
<span><Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="ContextualHelpContexts" InputFieldLabel="Help Contexts" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl></span>
```